# C# "Sometimes" socket listener gives an error after a client disconnected

Tags: c#, sockets, error-handling, console

I'm new in C# and I choose it because I must write server listener for clients... I'll build a server with threads which can listen to multiple clients without problem, but sometimes when a client disconnects the server gives an error.

> **System.InvalidOperationException: the operation is not allowed  non-connected**

this is my code where I receive packets:

```
NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, 312);
dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytesFrom).Replace("-","");
Console.WriteLine("\n " + hex + "\n_______________()()()______________");
```

and this is the console screenshot with error:
[Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek12k.png)

Comment: What do you want to acheive? Ignore the error? Log it? Do you just want to know why it happens? How do you want the community to help you?

Answer (score 2):

[TcpClient.GetStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx) will throw an exception if the socket is not or no longer connected.

Wrap the code in a try..catch block:

```
try
{
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, 312);
    dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytesFrom).Replace("-","");
    Console.WriteLine("\n " + hex + "\n_______________()()()______________");
} 
catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
{       
    // The TcpClient is not connected to a remote host.
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException odex)
{
    // The TcpClient has been closed.
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay but please i'm newbie in C# (i'm web developer) and if you can show me example, thanks

Comment: Sorry but being a newbie is no excuse. Just type "C# try catch" in your favourite web search engine. I cannot post code now.

Comment: i just wanted example, but thenks for all ...

Comment: i already have code like this
try{

}
 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
                }

Comment: @user1360571 you probably have that somewhere higher in the code hierarchy. You need in where you access the socket, so there you can detect and handle a disconnected client.